# How to transform a debezium message in JSON format such that it can be loaded into Redshift

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift, etl, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I need help to achieve few things. I have created a data pipeline as mentioned below.

Mysql-->debezium--> Kafka-->Kafka Connect--->AWS S3.

Now S3 will have a debezium event message in JSON format.

Now need to load this to Redshift as a table.

S3-->Redshift(Target Database) as rows.

Below I have shared a debezium event message for an single update event(Updated quantity of an product_id 102) and just want to have in a format which when I do copy command in S3, it should load the changes(Create/Update/Delete) into redshift table.

Note: here I have given "rotate.interval.ms": "3600000" for each our a debezium message file will be created which will have all CRUD actions.

So need a solution such that it transforms each newly created file in S3 which as debezium message events to a format where we can apply a copy command such that it loads in redshift.
**MY Main goal is to capture CDC Changes from MYSQL and replicate in Redshift.**

**This is my S3 sink Connector config:**
Kafka Connect S3 Sink:

```
{
  "name": "s3-sink-db02",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "s3.bucket.name": "S3bucket",
    "name": "s3-sink-db02",
    "tasks.max": "3",
    "s3.region": "us-east-1",
    "aws.access_key_id": "accesskey",
    "aws.secret_access_key": "secretKey",
    "s3.part.size": "5242880",
    "s3.compression.type": "gzip",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "locale": "en",
    "flush.size": "10000",
    "rotate.interval.ms": "3600000",
    "topics.regex": "dbserver1.(.*)",
    "internal.key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "internal.key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
    "internal.value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "internal.value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.HourlyPartitioner",
    "path.format": "YYYY/MM/dd/HH",
    "partition.duration.ms": "3600000",
    "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "3600000"
  }
}
```

**Debezium Message:**

```
{
  "schema": {
    "name": "dbserver1.inventory.orders.Envelope",
    "optional": false,
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "field": "before",
        "name": "dbserver1.inventory.orders.Value",
        "optional": true,
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "field": "order_number",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int32"
          },
          {
            "field": "order_date",
            "name": "io.debezium.time.Date",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int32",
            "version": 1
          },
          {
            "field": "purchaser",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int32"
          },
          {
            "field": "quantity",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int32"
          },
          {
            "field": "product_id",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int32"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "after",
        "name": "dbserver1.inventory.orders.Value",
        "optional": true,
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "field": "order_number",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int32"
          },
          {
            "field": "order_date",
            "name": "io.debezium.time.Date",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int32",
            "version": 1
          },
          {
            "field": "purchaser",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int32"
          },
          {
            "field": "quantity",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int32"
          },
          {
            "field": "product_id",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int32"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "source",
        "name": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.Source",
        "optional": false,
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "field": "version",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "field": "connector",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "field": "name",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "field": "ts_ms",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int64"
          },
          {
            "default": "false",
            "field": "snapshot",
            "name": "io.debezium.data.Enum",
            "optional": true,
            "type": "string",
            "version": 1,
            "parameters": {
              "allowed": "true,last,false"
            }
          },
          {
            "field": "db",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "field": "table",
            "optional": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "field": "server_id",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int64"
          },
          {
            "field": "gtid",
            "optional": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "field": "file",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "field": "pos",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int64"
          },
          {
            "field": "row",
            "optional": false,
            "type": "int32"
          },
          {
            "field": "thread",
            "optional": true,
            "type": "int64"
          },
          {
            "field": "query",
            "optional": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "op",
        "optional": false,
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "field": "ts_ms",
        "optional": true,
        "type": "int64"
      }
    ]
  },
  "payload": {
    "op": "u",
    "before": {
      "order_date": 16816,
      "quantity": 1,
      "purchaser": 1001,
      "order_number": 10001,
      "product_id": 102
    },
    "after": **{
  "order_date": 16816,
  "quantity": 6,
  "purchaser": 1001,
  "order_number": 10001,
  "product_id": 102
},
"source": {
    "query": null,
    "thread": 4,
    "server_id": 223344,
    "version": "1.0.3.Final",
    "file": "mysql-bin.000007",
    "connector": "mysql",
    "pos": 354,
    "name": "dbserver1",
    "gtid": null,
    "row": 0,
    "ts_ms": 1591620600000,
    "snapshot": "false",
    "db": "inventory",
    "table": "orders"
  },
  "ts_ms": 1591620602204
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of the json format, and also what you have tried so far within AWS Redshift to decode this.

Comment: Just bear in mind that there is a https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/configuration/event-flattening.html SMT that might give you format foor easier integration

Comment: @JonScott: I have re editted my question with example. I haven't tried to decode this.

Comment: @JiriPechanec : I have re edited my question with few examples and please let me know   whether this SMT will provide what I want.

Comment: @JiriPechanec: I read the link which you gave but SMT  "Default behavior is that the SMT drops Kafka records for DELETE operation change events because most consumers cannot yet handle them."

Comment: I am not familiar with S3 sink connector but from my experience with other sink connectors by applying the SMT you get the behaviour you are looking for. Regarding dropping deletes/tombstones - it is default but can be configured, see config options.